# Constructing a truth table (CPT) efficiently

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, bayesian-networks

I am working on an assignment on Probabilistic Reasoning for an AI intro course. I am having a bit of (programming) trouble with constructing the conditional probability tables (cpt) in a Bayesian Network.

I want to construct the cpt for a `BayesNode` object which has its set of `parents`. The cpt is actually a truth table, assigning true/false values to every one of the parents, and for each entry in that table, a probability should be computed.

This is what I have so far:

```
abstract class BayesNode<T> {

    ArrayList<BayesNode> parents;
    Map<Map<BayesNode,Boolean>, Probability> cpt = new HashMap<>(); 
}


void constructCpt() {

    constructEntries(new HashMap<>(), new LinkedList<>(this.parents));
}

private void constructEntries
        (Map<BayesNode, Boolean> tableEntry, Queue<BayesNode> left){

    if (left.size() == 0){
        cpt.put(new HashMap<>(tableEntry), computeConditionalProbability(tableEntry));
    }
    else{
        BayesNode nextParent = left.poll();

        tableEntry.put(nextParent,true);
        constructEntries(tableEntry, new LinkedList<>(left));

        tableEntry.put(nextParent, false);
        constructEntries(tableEntry, new LinkedList<>(left));

    }
}
```

`cpt` is the table itself, with its key being another `HashMap` which represents the entry in the table, and its value being a probability for that entry.

The inner map has the `BayesNode` as keys, and booleans as values.

While it seems to work so far, I have a feeling I got it wrong somehow, and perhaps there is a more elegant way of iterating the parents of the node in order to construct the table. Especially, I  worry that the repeated creation of `LinkedList` is just overflowing the heap unnecessarily.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: "I have a feeling I got it wrong somehow" suggests that you haven't built and executed a test plan.  Most of all you haven't demonstrated the operation and raised specific worries.  This is to say, you do not yet have a Stack Overflow type of question.  No input, no output, no tracing or debugging results ... SO is not for nebulous design help or code reviews.

Comment: Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778)